# Distribuição de pontos em html

Tags: php, html

fiz esse código aqui:

```html
<div class="snippet">
  <p>Habilidades:</p>

  <div>
    <label for="Passe">Passe</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="start" name="Passe" min="0" max="11">

  <div>
    <label for="Drible">Drible</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Drible" name="Drible" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Marcação">Marcação</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Marcação" name="Marcação" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Finalização">Finalização</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Finalização" name="Finalização" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Cabeceio">Cabeceio</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Cabeceio" name="Cabeceio" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Cruzamento">Cruzamento</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Cruzamento" name="Cruzamento" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Bola Parada">Bola Parada</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Bola Parada" name="Bola Parada" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">
  <div>
    <label for="Domínio">Domínio</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Domínio" name="Domínio" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Condução">Condução</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Condução" name="Condução" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Força">Força</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Força" name="Força" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Resistência">Resistência</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Resistência" name="Resistência" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Velocidade">Velocidade</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Velocidade" name="Velocidade" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Explosão">Explosão</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Explosão" name="Explosão" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Posicionamento">Posicionamento</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Posicionamento" name="Posicionamento" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Liderança">Liderança</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Liderança" name="Liderança" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">

  <div>
    <label for="Espírito de Equipe">Espírito de Equipe</label>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="Espírito de Equipe" name="Espírito de Equipe" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10">
</div>
```

e queria saber como faço distribuição de pontos, queria dar ao cliente 80 pontos que seriam distribuidos entre essas categorias

Comment: Basta utilizar JavaScript, somar as quantidades atuais com os 80 adicionais e definir o resultado como o máximo da soma dos atributos distribuídos. No seu exemplo ele começa com 1356 pontos já distribuídos, somando os 80 ele terá disponível 1436 pontos, assim você permite ele fazer a distribuição enquanto a soma não passar esse valor. Quer tentar?

Comment: Se o label e o input estão conectados é melhor eles ficarem dentro da mesma div

Comment: @ViniciusFernandes Por que?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss neste código nada de mais, mas é sempre bom manter a semântica e forma de estruturação do html, e no futuro facilita a estilização com css ou até mesmo se quiser usar um bootstrap

Comment: @ViniciusFernandes Terei que discordar. Não vejo como isso fere a semântica e deixar separados talvez seja justamente para facilitar a estilização hoje. Mas como isso não faz parte do escopo da pergunta, se quiser conversar mais entra lá no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss opa, como eu faria isso amigo? pode me ajudar?

Comment: Seu código tem erros tb: um `id` não pode ter espaços. Outra coisa, procure usar id's simples, sem acentos. Por exemplo, em vez de `id="Marcação"`, use `id="marcacao"`. No caso de `id="Espírito de Equipe"`, poderia usar `id="espirito_de_equipe"`, ou `id="EspiritoDeEquipe"`, ou `id="espiritodeequipe"`.. lembrando que o CSS e o JavaScript são _case sensitive_ (diferenciam maiúsculas de minúsculas). **Obs.:** Os `name` a mesma coisa.

Comment: obrigado sou novo no ramo, estou usando o javascript para fazer a limitação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que consegui e ainda dei uma melhorada pra ver se te dá uma idéia, a lógica é bem simples mas ´tbm bati um pouco a cabeça.

```
<div class="snippet">
    <p>Habilidades:</p>

    <div>
        <label for="Passe">Passe</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="start" name="Passe" min="0" max="11" value="0">
        <input type="number" id="showstart" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Drible">Drible</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Drible" name="Drible" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showDrible" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Marcação">Marcação</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Marcação" name="Marcação" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showMarcação" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Finalização">Finalização</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Finalização" name="Finalização" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showFinalização" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Cabeceio">Cabeceio</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Cabeceio" name="Cabeceio" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showCabeceio" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Cruzamento">Cruzamento</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Cruzamento" name="Cruzamento" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showCruzamento" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Bola Parada">Bola Parada</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Bola-Parada" name="Bola Parada" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showBola-Parada" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Domínio">Domínio</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Domínio" name="Domínio" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showDomínio" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Condução">Condução</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Condução" name="Condução" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showCondução" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Força">Força</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Força" name="Força" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showForça" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Resistência">Resistência</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Resistência" name="Resistência" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showResistência" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Velocidade">Velocidade</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Velocidade" name="Velocidade" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showVelocidade" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Explosão">Explosão</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Explosão" name="Explosão" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showExplosão" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Posicionamento">Posicionamento</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Posicionamento" name="Posicionamento" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showPosicionamento" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Liderança">Liderança</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Liderança" name="Liderança" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showLiderança" readonly="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Espírito de Equipe">Espírito de Equipe</label>
        <input type="range" class="habilidades" id="Espirito-de-Equipe" name="Espirito-de-Equipe" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10">
        <input type="number" id="showEspirito-de-Equipe" readonly="">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="teste"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".habilidades").val(0);
    });
    var limite = 80;
    var total = 0;
    $(".habilidades").change(function() {
        total = 0;
        $("#show"+$(this).attr('id')).val($(this).val());
        $(".habilidades").each(function(){
            total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
            $("#teste").empty();
            $("#teste").append(total);
        });
        if(total > limite){
            alert("Você passou do limite de:" + limite);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Qualquer Dúvida é só comentar.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Caso queira colocar o código dentro da tag `<head></head>` coloque todo o bloco com JS dentro do `$(document).ready`. e caso a resposta esteja correta marcar a respondida.

Comment: opa mano, como faço para integrar esse seu código a página?

Comment: Como assim? é só copiar e colar.

Comment: ja consegui amigo, vlw de vdd